# PrestaShop: translate INVOICE in to FACTURE in the invoice pdf

Tags: translation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, invoice

How can I customise the invoice pdf in prestashop?
I want to replace the "INVOICE" in the pdf by "FACTURE" because my store is en french.

Trying to get this result:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Prestashop 1.7.0.4, all the translation in the admin are OK but it is still write in english.

I did a modification on the template invoice, I hope Prestashop team will fix it quickly!
file : /pdf/header.tpl
for the first , replace with :

```
<td style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt; color: #444; width: 100%;">
            {if isset($header) && $header|escape:'html':'UTF-8'|upper != "INVOICE"}{$header|escape:'html':'UTF-8'|upper}{/if}
            {if isset($header) && $header|escape:'html':'UTF-8'|upper == "INVOICE"}FACTURE{/if}
            </td>
```

It is not the best solution, but I don't have a better solution for now... there is too much "bugs" with this 1.7 :(

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that PDF translations are under classic theme and shop will use those translations if primary theme does not have them. There is two sections to translate: Modules and Shop. It will be under Shop.

Answer (score 0):

In your backoffice go to: "Localization > Translation", in type of translation select `PDF translations`.

Now if you don't have make an override of invoice.tpl in 'Select your theme' select 'Core', otherwise you have to select the reference theme.

Then select your language and click on 'Modify'.

Here find 'Invoice' and change as you want :)